# location.reload() prevents POST from succeeding

Tags: javascript, post

I have the following code in a function that is called by the onClick attribute of an HTML button.

What it should do is POST to the .jsp, write to the console on success, and then reload the page. What happens, however, is that the message is written to the console (ie., the success condition was called), the page reloads, but the .jsp doesn't run (I have it in debug, and it doesn't even register anything).

Interestingly, commenting out the location.reload() or simply putting a breakpoint on it gets things to work.

Why would this be the case?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Move.jsp",
    data: { action: 'move',
        nodeID: nodeID
    },
    success: console.log("Moved " + nodeID)
});
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A in AJAX stands for "Asynchronous". Your `$.ajax()` call basically runs in the background and doesn't interfere with your other code, so `location.reload()` executes immediately after, regardless of whether the POST request was sent or not.

Also, `console.log()` should be inside of an anonymous function to be executed correctly.

You can either make it synchronous (this will lock up the browser until the request completes):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Move.jsp",
    async: false,
    data: {
        action: 'move',
        nodeID: nodeID
    }
});

console.log("Moved " + nodeID);
location.reload();
```

Or move your `location.reload()` into the callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Move.jsp",
    data: {
        action: 'move',
        nodeID: nodeID
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("Moved " + nodeID);
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: That was it. I was under the (mistaken) impression that the execution of the success function implied the completion of the POST.

Answer (score 0):

You refresh the page before the ajax call had a chance to POST.

**Move your reload into the success handler:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Move.jsp",
    data: {
        action: 'move',
        nodeID: nodeID
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("Moved " + nodeID);
        location.reload();
    }
});
```